# How to use OpenLayers DrawFeature with Selenium WebDriver in Java (double click issue)?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, openlayers, double-click

I am testing a GIS API that is based on OpenLayers. I use Selenium WebDriver to perform the tests. I am now trying to test the OpenLayers.DrawFeature. It works fine when drawing points, which require a single click. But for lines and polygons it doesn't.

Line and polygon drawing requires a double click to finish drawing the shape. But, the "doubleClick()" method from Selenium WebDriver doe not seem to work.

It is a work task, so I can't paste the whole code, but here is what I think is the crucial part:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
Global.initWithCookies(driver);

// Gets the button to select a shape to draw
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id(Menu.idOfDrawModesBtn()));
// Creates an action
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
// Moves the cursor to the element
act.moveToElement(el).perform();
// Gets the button to draw a polygon
driver.findElement(By.id(Menu.idOfDrawModePolygonBtn())).click();
// Gets the map element
el = driver.findElement(By.id(Global.idOfMapDiv()));
// Moves the cursor to the element
act.moveToElement(el).perform();

// First click at the center of the map
act.click().perform();
// Moves to 2nd location
act.moveByOffset(100, 10).perform();
// 2nd click creates the 2nd vertex of the polygon
act.click().perform();
// Moves to 2nd location
act.moveByOffset(200, -200).perform();
/* Double click creates the 3rd vertex of the polygon
    AND should finish the drawing */
act.doubleClick().perform();

driver.close();
```

As you can see here, the polygon is not drawn yet, because the double click didn't work:

[image: without_double_click]

This is what it should look like, if the double click worked:

[image: with_double_click]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have found a solution. It works, but I don't understand why.

Instead of:

```
act.doubleClick().perform();
```

I did:

```
act.click().doubleClick().build().perform();
```

So, I perform a normal click, THEN a double click, I build the action, and perform.

It is working. I am able to finish the drawing.

Comment: Hi joaorodr84, I've a similar issue but non for drawing ... I've to identify a feature on my map based on OpenLayers 2.x (ExtJS). Do you've any sample?

Comment: I don't work with ExtJS, but if you want to share your code, I can take a look at it a give a suggestion.

Comment: ExtJS it's not fundamental. I've tried to open a new question on this matter trying to simplify my use case: if you want you can reply here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045296/selenium-web-driver-and-openlayers-2-x-how-to-do-a-identify-on-a-map. I've also another similar question (interactive zoom in on a map ....): here you are another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059378/selenium-web-driver-and-openlayers-2-x-how-to-do-an-interactive-zoom-in-on-a-ma. Any suggestion, sample, code will be appreciated!!! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I don't have any code now because .... don't know how to get started in both cases!!! :-(

Comment: Hi @joaorodr84 I've tried to put a sample of the code I'm using here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045296/selenium-web-driver-and-openlayers-2-x-how-to-do-a-identify-on-a-map

Comment: Hi @joaorodr84 i have issue in calculating the offset values from the center to the polygon , do you have any idea how to calculate these values ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51633480/how-to-find-the-offset-value-of-the-polygon-from-center-on-openlayers

Comment: Hi @joaorodr84 Thanks for the answer. It worked for me as well but can you please explain these 3 lines of your code? 'driver.findElement(By.id(Menu.idOfDrawModePolygonBtn())).click();'
'el = driver.findElement(By.id(Global.idOfMapDiv()));'
'act.moveToElement(el).perform();'
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Me_developer I just added comments to the main post. Hope they help. :)

Comment: @joaorodr84 Thanks a lot. :)