# Selenium Web Driver and OpenLayers 2.x: how to do an interactive zoom in on a map?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, openlayers

I've to test a web mapping application that use OpenLayers 2.x, using Selenium WebDriver in Java and using Firefox (I'm on Windows 7).

I've have to test the interactive zoom in on the map, so:

1) click SHIFT+Left-button mouse

2) drag the mouse drawing a box in the map (I'm not able to do this ....)

3) release the Left-button mouse: at this time the map response is a zoom in (I'm not able to do this ....)

I can't give the url of my application that it's not public but I can use this simple test case

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/example.html

that shows my use case.

Suggestions? Samples?

Thank you very much in advance!

Cesare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved!

Here you are the code that works: you can excute it!

```
package myTestProjects;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class interactiveZoomInOpenLayerstest_01 {

private static WebDriver driver = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //Create a new profile and load my Firefox default profile  
    System.out.println("Creo un nuovo profilo e vi carico il profilo Firefox di test con DEMO 27 ...");
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();        
    FirefoxProfile ffProfile = profile.getProfile("default");

    // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver using my new Firefox profile  
    System.out.println("Creo una nuova sessione del browser Firefox ...");
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffProfile);

    //Put a Implicit wait, this means that any search for elements on the page could take the time the implicit wait is set for before throwing exception
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    // It is always advisable to Maximize the window before performing DragNDrop action
    System.out.println("Massimizzo la finestra del browser ...");
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();        

    //Launch the OpenLayers 2.x  sample 
    System.out.println("Mi collego all'esempio di OpenLayers 2.x ...");
    Thread.sleep(3000L); 
    driver.get("http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/example.html");


    // Find the viewport inside in witch there is the map   
    System.out.println("Individuo il viewport al cui interno c'è la mappa ...");
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.id("OpenLayers_Map_2_OpenLayers_ViewPort"));

    // Create a new Action instance 
    System.out.println("Creo un oggetto di tipo \"Action\" ...");
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);

    // Moves to 2nd location
    System.out.println("Moves to 1st location: 200, 150 ...");
    Thread.sleep(3000L);

    // Draw rectangle and execute zoom in
    System.out.println("Moves to 1st location: 200, 150 ...");
    act.moveToElement(el,200,50).click().keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).clickAndHold().moveToElement(el, 300, 150).click().release().keyUp(Keys.SHIFT).build().perform();

    // Print TEST = OK!!
    System.out.println("TEST = OK !!");
    //driver.quit();

}

}
```