# How to find the offset value of the Polygon from center on Openlayers

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, openlayers, vaadin8

i calculated the (x1,Y1) and (x2,Y2) and calculated the difference between them (Blue line ) and gave those pixel values to driver to click but i am not able to click on the polygon (Point).
1.First the mouse will go to center of the map where (x1,y1)=(960,520) according to the window but the driver will consider those values as (0,0).
2. Now i need to calculate the offset values from center to each polygon on the map.(x1,y1)=(960,520) and (x2,y2)=(1000,232)

> the difference between the (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) will give me the
>   distance of the point from center.for ex:(x3,y3)

[image]

the code below

```
try {
            driver.get("http://localhost:8090/demo/");
            System.out.println("demo opened");
            Thread.sleep(15000);

            WebElement can = driver.findElements(By.tagName("canvas")).get(0);
            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            builder.moveToElement(can,0,0).click().perform();
            Thread.sleep(12000);

            WebElement eler1x = driver
                    .findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[17]/div"));
            String val1 = eler1x.getText();
            System.out.println(val1);
            WebElement eler1y = driver
                    .findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[19]/div"));
            String val2 = eler1y.getText();
            System.out.println(val2);
            double x1 = Double.parseDouble(val1);
        //error line    double y1 = Double.parseDouble(val1);
            double y1 = Double.parseDouble(val2);
            int r2x1 = (int) x1;
            int r2y1 = (int) y1;
            builder.moveByOffset(r2x1, r2y1);
            builder.click().build().perform();
            System.out.println("executed");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
```

i gave the difference between (x3,Y3) as offset value for the driver , the test case passed but no click on the point or polygon .can anyone give example or suggestion how to calculate the offset values on the Openlayers

Comment: Whether you have drawn all the three lines using Selenium Webdriver ? or is it defaulted in your URL(created using Open Layers library)?

Comment: @Subburaj , actually there is no lines on the map ,Only points and polygon will be there on the map when it is rendered . i draw the lines  on the map  using paint to give clarification for the question. 1) first the driver is going to center of the map and from their it is clicking all the polygons or point , now the question is How to calculate Offset distance between the center point and the remaining polygons or points? i need to give the offset values for the  driver for the method moveByOffset(x-offset, y-offset)  in Actions class in selenium

Comment: @RamanaMuttana Don't you have a mistake here? `double y1 = Double.parseDouble(val1);` Shouldn't it be `val2`?

Comment: @joaorodr84 you are correct , i will change

Comment: @joaorodr84  yes it works perfectly , thanks for finding the mistake